# AI ML for Pattern Classification in Data Frame

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have a dataset on which I want to apply AI/ML algorithm to classify patterns as given below, please suggest to me the ways in which I can do it efficiently.

Example Dataset-

```
Name    Subset    Value    
A       X_1       55
A       X_A       89
A       X_B       45
B       B_1       55
B       B_A       89
C       X_1       66
C       X_A       656
C       X_B       456
D       D_1       545
D       D_2       546
D       D_3       895
D       D_4       565
```

The output would be;

```
Pattern No.    Instance    Pattern
1              1           A       X_1       55
                           A       X_A       89
                           A       X_B       45
               2           C       X_1       66
                           C       X_A       656
                           C       X_B       456
2              1           B       B_1       55
                           B       B_A       89
3              1           D       D_1       545
                           D       D_2       546
                           D       D_3       895
                           D       D_4       565
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a clustering algorithm.

- Define a distance function between instances
- Try various clustering algorithms

I would recommend to start with Jaccard distance and Agglomerative clustering.

Code example

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering


def read_data():
    text = '''A       X_1       55
A       X_A       89
A       X_B       45
B       B_1       55
B       B_A       89
C       X_1       66
C       X_A       656
C       X_B       456
D       D_1       545
D       D_2       546
D       D_3       895
D       D_4       565'''

    data = [re.split('\s+', line) for line in text.split('\n')]
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=re.split('\s+', 'Name    Subset    Value'))

df = read_data()

instances = []
for name, name_df in df.groupby('Name'):
    instances.append({'name': name, 'subsets': name_df['Subset'].tolist()})
    
def jaccard_distance(list_1, list_2):
    set_1 = set(list_1)
    set_2 = set(list_2)
    return 1 - len(set_1.intersection(set_2)) / len(set_1.union(set_2))

clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None,
                                     distance_threshold=1,
                                     affinity='precomputed',
                                     linkage='average')
distance_matrix = [
    [
        jaccard_distance(instance_1['subsets'], instance_2['subsets'])
        for instance_2 in instances
    ] for instance_1 in instances
]
clusters = clustering.fit_predict(distance_matrix)
for instance, cluster in zip(instances, clusters):
    instance['cluster'] = cluster

print(instances)
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'A', 'subsets': ['X_1', 'X_A', 'X_B'], 'cluster': 0},
 {'name': 'B', 'subsets': ['B_1', 'B_A'], 'cluster': 2},
 {'name': 'C', 'subsets': ['X_1', 'X_A', 'X_B'], 'cluster': 0},
 {'name': 'D', 'subsets': ['D_1', 'D_2', 'D_3', 'D_4'], 'cluster': 1}]
```

Comment: How can I use K Means Clustering?

Comment: @SHLOKDOSHI, K-Means works with Euqlidean distance. Сonvert data about instances to vectors (points) with the same dimensions. I don't know what subnets are, but you can try binary encoding. A vector will have as many dimensions as many different subnets you have. Every coordinate in a vector will correspond to a fact if instance has a subnet (1.0 or 0.0). Also, I would recommend to normalize vectors to the same length before clustering